# JavaScript, Highcharts - change chart data by dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have a pie chart in a container where I would like to change the data displayed based on a dropdown action:

```
<select class="selectHeaderMobile large-1 behaviourForm" id = "list">
              <option value="">Select Metric</option>
              <option value="A">Difficulty</option>
              <option value="B">Interest</option>
  </select>
<button class="button smallMobile show-for-all" type="button" id="change">Apply</button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var options {  // Build the chart
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            renderTo: 'feedback1',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Difficulty'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
         credits: {
      enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    showInLegend: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    },
                    connectorColor: 'silver'
                }
            }
        },
         series: [{
            name: 'Difficulty',
            data: <%= @get_difficulty_pie.to_json %>
        }]
    };
            var chart = new Highcharts.chart(options);
$("#list").on('change', function(){
    //alert('f')
    var selVal = $("#list").val();
    if(selVal == "A" || selVal == '')
    {
        options.series = [{name: 'Difficulty', data: <%= @get_difficulty_pie.to_json %> }]
    }
    else if(selVal == "B")
    {
        options.series = [{name: 'Interest', data: <%= @get_interest_pie.to_json %>}]
    }
    chart = Highchart.chart(options);   
});
)};

</script>
```

The data is being returned but nothing is displayed indicating a syntax error somewhere but i'm not sure and I can't test the dropdown.

Page source:

```
         series: [{
            name: 'Difficulty',
            data: [4,2,1,6,3,3,1,6,4,5,2,6]
        },
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

$("#list").on('change', function(){
    //alert('f')
    var selVal = $("#list").val();
    if(selVal == "A" || selVal == '')
    {
        options.series = [{name: 'Difficulty', data: [4,2,1,6,3,3,1,6,4,5,2,6] }]
    }
    else if(selVal == "B")
    {
        options.series = [{name: 'Interest', data: [4,3,null,3,null,3,4,6,6,3,5,5]}]
    }

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);    
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: please re-create your problem in JSFiddle or a Plnkr.

Comment: Hi @mcranston18,  this is exactly what I am looking to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/WDcL4/ if that helps. I followed this example.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/CO22/L03tdkf9/3/ here is mine...

Comment: There are quite a few syntax errors in that code. Check your browser console for error messages (http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some issues in you code :

- you don't close correctly your first variable "option", there is a bracket missing
- you pass to the variable chart (which is a Highchart object) the variable option which is also a Highchart object, it will not work.

You can do that :

```
var options = { /* highchart options */ } 

var chart = new Highchart.chart(options) 

$list.on('change',function() {

   // blabla change variable options 

   chart = Highchart.chart(options) // it reload the chart with new options 

});
```

Comment: Thanks, updated op javascript based on suggestions...still no success

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L03tdkf9/  Sorry only started with it if done something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, fixed and works now:

Button html same as above. Was just syntax errors.

```
<script>
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'feedback1',
        defaultSeriesType: 'pie'
        },
         title: {
            text: 'Difficulty/Interest'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
    plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                 dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
    series: [{name: 'Difficulty', data: <%= @get_difficulty_pie.to_json %>}]
};
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

$("#list").on('change', function(){
    //alert('f')
    var selVal = $("#list").val();
    if(selVal == "A" || selVal == '')
    {
        options.series =  [{name: 'Difficulty', data: <%= @get_difficulty_pie.to_json %>}]
    }
    else if(selVal == "B")
    {
        options.series = [{name: 'Interest', data: <%= @get_interest_pie.to_json %>}]
    }  
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);    
});

</script>
```